How to make a custom button visible for only 5 people?
I have a list where I have a column I formatted in JSON to show an approval button.
The button only needs to display for 5 fixed persons.
How can I set this up?
I already tried with the mailadres == @me but it's not working.
 "display": "=if([$Status] == 'Aangevraagd' && 'svc.powerautomate@contoso.com' == @me , 'inherit','none')"


Is it working fine for 1 user? If yes, try using below given solution. Let me know if it works for you.

You can use toLowerCase() operator for email case sensitive issue, I have updated my answer below.

Is there any update?

Try using expressions for display property like this:
"display": "=if([$Status] == 'Aangevraagd' && ('user1@contoso.com' == @me || 'user2@contoso.com' == @me || 'user3@contoso.com' == @me || 'user4@contoso.com' == @me || 'user5@contoso.com' == @me), 'inherit', 'none')"

Documentation:

Use column formatting to customize SharePoint
SharePoint JSON formatting syntax reference


Update from comments:
You can use toLowerCase() operator for email case sensitive issue, use JSON like:
"display": "=if([$Status] == 'Aangevraagd' && (toLowerCase('user1@contoso.com') == toLowerCase(@me) || toLowerCase('user2@contoso.com') == toLowerCase(@me) || toLowerCase('user3@contoso.com') == toLowerCase(@me) || toLowerCase('user4@contoso.com') == toLowerCase(@me) || toLowerCase('user5@contoso.com') == toLowerCase(@me)), 'inherit', 'none')"

